# Genymotion and a CPU without SSSE3

Tags: android, cpu, genymotion

I tried to launched an app in Genymotion but it instantly failed. The log [1] indicated the fact that the set of SSSE3 instructions is missing.

```
F/libYourApp.so( 1571): (null):0 ((null)): Aborted. Incompatible processor: missing feature 0x10 - ssse3.
```

Indeed, my processor does not support the set of instructions - see /proc/cpuinfo [2]

Can this be worked around? Or is the only option to buy a newer CPU?

[1] http://paste.ubuntu.com/10939987/ 
[2] http://paste.ubuntu.com/10938859/

Comment: looks like your build of qt for android requires sse3. you could maybe try to recompile it with  -no-sse3

Comment: Even after adding `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mno-sse3 -mno-sse4 -mno-ssse3` the app fails. This suggests that the whole library may need it, not only the app. But I have no idea how to recompile the whole Qt for Android.

Comment: you can find the howto here: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt5ForAndroidBuilding